# Auto Focus webcam before snapping image with OPENCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How do I enable the webcam to auto focus before snapping the image?

My code for capturing the image is as shown:

```
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); // capture from video device #0


    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH , 800); 
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture ,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT , 600); 


    if(!cvGrabFrame(capture))  //if no webcam detected or failed to capture anything
    {              
        cout << "Could not grab a frame\n\7";
        exit(0);
    }

    IplImage* img=cvRetrieveFrame(capture);           // retrieve the captured frame
}
```

I have tried using wait key, etc, tried googling but to no avail. Does anybody have any idea how I can ensure that autofocus is applied already before snapping the image? Cuz the image now is a little more "blurry" than I would like it.

Comment: Normally focus settings are on the camera itself, what brand of webcam are you using?

Comment: Logitech. c920. comparing to using it in video, and allowing it to auto focus, and snapping immediately, there is a obvious contrast in quality.

Comment: @rockinfresh Did you have a look at this info http://lieksa.pp.fi/oh7fes/cameras/focus.htm ?

Comment: @uvts_cvs, Thanks. Didn't find anything like this through google. Please do consider posting it as the answer. It worked(:

Comment: @rockinfresh I added an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page "[Logitech webcam B910, C910 and C920 Auto-focus fix](http://lieksa.pp.fi/oh7fes/cameras/focus.htm)" it seems that the focus on Logitech C920 webcam is factory adjusted for short and medium distances. The same page has some instructions about changing the factory setup.